# restoring debian user access

Tags: ssh, debian, sudo

I have accidentally set the owner for all files and folders in the /home folder to 'root' (and a lot of other folders also) and now when I ssh into the server as myusername, I get the following error:

```
Could not chdir to home directory /home/myusername: Permission denied
-bash: /home/myusername/.bash_profile: Permission denied
```

At least it lets me login, but I can't do much. I only have my user and root as users, but root can't ssh in. I can't sudo as it gives "-bash: sudo: command not found" and if I try and switch to root it states "su: Authentication failure" even though I'm using the correct password. I can cd to most folders however.

Is there any way I can switch to root or chown folders which are currently owned by root?

Comment: I would have thought `su` would work. Did you try to specify the path to `sudo`? e.g. `/usr/bin/sudo -s`

Comment: Thanks Ryan, but I've checked that path at there's no sign of sudo - looks like sudo hasn't been installed. I can't install it either as I can't get su access.

Comment: The only other things I can think of are to login from the console and it that fails,  to boot into single user mode. You don't have console access do you?